# Why is my gradient printing like a faint white box?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I am trying to print from an Illustrator file and my items with gradients/shadows look fine on screen but when printed I get a faint white box. What setting am I missing??

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE. Can you make sure your document color mode are CMYK rather than RGB?

Comment: It is already CMYK set for business card design from the beginning

Comment: are you the same user that asked this question? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128046/gradient-print-problem-in-illustrator If so please don't post the same question multiple times; instead [edit] to make it better. Also check how to merge your accounts https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous

Comment: great news is that i found the answer here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/indesign-and-pdf-printing-boxes-instead-of-shadows-onscreen-looks-perfect

Answer (score 0):

[Printing gradients, meshes, and color blends](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/using/printing-gradients-meshes-color-blends.html) From Adobe help Page:

Files with gradients, meshes, or color blends can be difficult for some printers to print smoothly (without discrete bands of color) or at all. Follow these general guidelines to improve the printed results:

- Use a blend that changes at least 50% between two or more
  process-color components.
- Use shorter blends. The optimum length depends on the colors in your
  blend, but try to keep blends shorter than 7.5 inches.
- Use lighter colors, or make dark blends short. Banding is most likely
  to occur between very dark colors and white.
- Use an appropriate line screen that retains 256 levels of gray.
- If you create a gradient between two or more spot colors, assign
  different screen angles to the spot colors when you create color
  separations. If you’re not sure what the angles should be, consult
  your print shop.
- Print to an output device that supports PostScript® Language Level 3
  whenever possible.
- If you have to print to an output device that supports Postscript
  Language Level 2, or when printing meshes that include transparency,
  you can choose to rasterize gradients and meshes during printing. As
  a result, Illustrator converts gradients and meshes from vector
  objects to JPEG images.

**Rasterize gradients and meshes during printing**

- Choose File > Print.
- Select Graphics on the left side of the Print dialog box, and select Compatible Gradient And Gradient Mesh Printing.